# EKS Server Endpoint Access

Tags: kubernetes, networking, amazon-eks

I have a EKS Cluster v1.25. I have configured private and public endpoint access and add advanced setup with access to Kubernetes API only by specific IPs. Everything is working properly, except when I am trying to access the cluster from Jenkins EC2 instance which is in the same VPC. I have whitelisted the public IP of the instance, but when I am trying to access the cluster from it is going through private route and I got timeout? How to resolve this except adding 0.0.0.0/0?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Make sure that the respective security groups and network ACLs allow the necessary egress and ingress traffic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the private IP of your Jenkins EC2 instance. It should start with 172.X.X.X. If you can't find the private IP of your Jenkins EC2 instance, you can use your VPC subnet, such as 10.X.X.X/16.